# How to specify order of spring handler interceptors in xml configuration file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-aop, interceptor

I want to use two handler interceptors in my spring project. First interceptor to authenticate token. Second interceptor to store authenticated token in spring context. I am using xml interceptor configuration. How to specify order for handler interceptors.

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
        <bean class="com.megapath.interceptor.TokenValidatorInterceptor">               
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
        <bean class="com.megapath.interceptor.TokenStoreInterceptor">               
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 `mvc:interceptors` (note that it is plural not singular!) blocks? Put them in a single `mvc:interceptors` in the order you want them executed. You don't need the mapping for `/**` as that is the default.

Comment: I have coded them in single mvc:interceptors. For sake of question I have added two separate interceptors.

Comment: THe order you defined them in is the order they are executed in.

Comment: Okay. I will try with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum). The order in which you define interceptors is the order they get executed.